# Can't receive the data from device RFB2000 in python

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I am using the module "ctypes" to load  RFBClient.dll,I use windll and the convention is stdcall. I want to remote control the device RFB2000 with these commands below:
[first step for connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG3XB.png)
[All the commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqYuP.png)
for my programme, the connection is successful but the problem is that i can't recieve the data, when I want to get temperature value, I call the function but it always returns 0, the restype is c_double and the argtypes is none, I can't see there is any problem. English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

```
import ctypes
import time

libc = ctypes.WinDLL("X:\\RFBClient.dll")      
#connect to RFB software
libc.OpenRFBConnection(ctypes.c_char_p('127.0.0.1'.encode('UTF-8')))
#check if connection successful
libc.Connected()

#Set parameters
#num_automeas    = 1; %Number of auto-measurement runs. 
completion_count = 2; #% Number of On-Off pairs within each auto-measurement run.
OnHalfCycleTimeCount  = 40; # set 2s on 
OffHalfCycleTimeCount = 40; # set 2s off
Data=[]
libc.SetCompletionCount(completion_count)
libc.SetMeasureUntilCount(completion_count)
libc.SetOnHalfCycleCount(OnHalfCycleTimeCount)
libc.SetOffHalfCycleCount(OffHalfCycleTimeCount)

libc.NewAutoMeasurement()
#zeroing
time.sleep(1)
print("zeroing.....")
libc.Zero()
while libc.Zeroing()== -1:
  time.sleep(1)
#libc.CheckingSensor()
print("measurement start")
libc.StartMeas()
time.sleep(0.5)
while libc.Measuring() == -1:
  time.sleep(1)
print(libc.Measuring())

getTemperature = libc.GetTemperature
getTemperature.restype = ctypes.c_double
getTemperature.argtypes = []
print(getTemperature())
```

Comment: Things look right.  Does it work with the same calls in a C/C++ program?  FYI, you can simplify `libc.OpenRFBConnection(ctypes.c_char_p('127.0.0.1'.encode('UTF-8')))` to `libc.OpenRFBConnection(b'127.0.0.1')`.

Comment: Thanks, it works in a Delphi program. It is almost the same program, I can't figure out what's the problem.